# Why there's both a netstandard and netstandardapp TFM's?

Tags: .net, .net-core

In the new .NET Platform Standard we have the netstandard TFM (Target Framework Moniker) which allows us to target one specific version of the standard. This gives access to the available API's on that version in our code.

Apart from the netstandard TFM we also have the netstandardapp. I didn't get it. Why do we need those two? If we want to target the .NET Platform Standard don't we just need to target the netstandard TFM?

Comment: None of this stuff works yet, they have to come up with different temporary names to keep going.  Again, questions like these are only useful a year from now.

Comment: @HansPassant It's been quite the journey: `k10`, `aspnetcore50`, `dnxcore50`/`dotnet`. But I have a feeling it's finally going to land on `netstandard` for the libraries and `netstandardapp` for the applications.

Comment: A bunch of people (myself included) are hoping `netstandard` can be used in the near future. The current situation is suboptimal. I believe both `netstandard` and `netstandardapp` are available in the current Visual Studio RC (Update 2 RC 2).

Answer (score 6):

Think of it as the difference between a class library--`netstandard`--and a console app--`netstandardapp`.  There is currently no difference in terms of APIs.

In theory, `netstandardapp` could include an additional app model (or APIs) for console apps. This would be similar to how `uap` adds the Universal Windows app model to `netstandard`.

Personally, I think it's a case of YAGNI too, but I'm pretty sure this is the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Oh dear, I spoke too soon. Now there's `netcoreapp` (see [NuGet/Home#2299](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2299))

Comment: And now they have different names again :)